# работа метода Object.GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, .net

вычитал в [книге](http://oz.by/books/more1051976.html) про одну компанию которая конкатенировала строку логина и пароля и получала хешкод вызовом этого метода, заносила его в куки что бы пометить авторизированных пользователей, но потом Microsoft поменяла алгоритм хеширования и многие пользователи не смогли получить доступ к своим учётным записям.
Неужели в хотя бы в тысячи строк не найдётся две разные строки которые выдадут одинаковый хеш? Так же в книге говорилось что так делать не надо, подскажите алгоритм хеширования что бы в будущем я не писал такие методы авторизации.

Answer (score 4):

1. Никаких гарантий нет на то, что значения хешкода не поменяются между запусками приложения. Поэтому компания, которая на это рассчитывала, сама виновата в проблемах своих пользователей, нечего винить Microsoft. Хранить хешкод для использовании при следующем пробеге программы неверно, он имеет право поменяться.
2. Разумеется, хешкоды разных строк с логином/паролем вполне могут совпадать! То, что на основе хешкода от логина/пароля была построена безопасность — ещё одна ошибка.
3. Авторизация должна не быть основана на хешкоде. Объект, представляющий собой пользователя, нужно создавать на основе логина или на том, что в вашей системе уникально идентифицирует пользователя. Хешкод тут вовсе не при чём, он не идентифицирует пользователя.

Answer (score 2):

В книге говорится правильно. Метод GetHashCode не предназначен для решения задач связанных с авторизацией. С его помощью осуществляется иднетификация объекта при  проверке на равенство. Подробнее можете почитать на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx).

В подобных случаях лучше использовать из пространства имён [System.Security.Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx). Например, тот же [MD5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: А зачем md5, пардон? md5 — такой же хеш, он точно так же имеет право повторяться.

Comment: Вот как раз повторяться он права не имеет. 
В .Net есть варианты - MD5, SHA (128/256/512) и т.д.

Comment: @VladD, в случае md5 гарантируется вероятность случайной коллизии в 2^-128, что очень мало. Но, разумеется, алгоритм md5 давно устарел, против него есть много атак. Сейчас актуален алгоритм SHA-3, также можно использовать (пока не взломан) SHA-512 (это модификация SHA-2).

Comment: @VladD, по поводу же того, зачем его использовать - тут все просто. Если вместо паролей хранить просоленные хеши - то даже имея на руках базу данных, злоумышленник не сможет авторизоваться от имени пользователя. Также такая мера спасет тех пользователей, кто использует одинаковые пароли к разным сервисам в случае взлома одного из сервисов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Вместо паролей — понимаю. Но чтобы идентифицировать экаунт — увольте, не понимаю.

Answer (score 2):

Суть алгоритма Хеширования и состоит в том, чтобы обеспечивать "лавинный эффект".
Изменение хотя бы одного бита должно кардинально менять значение хэш-функции. Но есть коллизии т.е. совпадение результатов, когда они не должны совпадать.
Тщательно выбирать саму хэшфункцию не имеет особого смысла.
Просто не применяйте подобный паттерн, это bad practice.
Прислушайтесь к ответу @VladD и @Streletz.

Answer (score 0):

Хеш в куках иногда хранят для локального разделения пользовательских сессий между собой (хотя это не имеет прямого отношения к авторизации). Например, когда нужно предоставить пользователю возможность запускать одно и то же веб-приложение одновременно в нескольких окнах браузера. Чтобы каждый экземпляр веб-приложения использовал только свой кук, каждый кук маркируют уникальным идентификатором на основе хеша. Вероятность их повторения в период сеанса работы стремится к нулю. С появлением локальных хранилищ (DOM) у браузеров этот метод стал менее популярным.